# Bins and colored balls: minimum number of bins containing a subset of colored balls

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

We are given $n$ bins and $dm$ colored balls. There are $m$ colors in total such that there are exactly $d$ balls of each color. For each color, we randomly choose $d$ bins and put the $d$ balls of this color in the chosen bins. Now given a set $\cal T$ of $t$ colors among the $m$ colors, let $z_{min}$ denote the minimum number of bins such that (1) for each of the $t$ colors in $\cal T$, there is at least a bin containing balls of this color, and (2) these bins do not contain balls of any other color. I want to compute $\mathbb{E}[z_{min}]$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? My wild guess is, for sufficiently large values, you'd use the normal approximation to the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Thank you Berry. I have no clue how to approach the problem, so I am looking for comments on the analytical tools that I can use. I expect (or I want) that with appropriate values of $n,m$, $z_{min}$ is sub-linear in $t$.

Comment: To define an expectation, you perhaps need to know what value $z_\text{min}$ takes in the (maybe rare) case where there is no set of bins satisfying both (1) and (2)? And yes, there are certainly regimes where the expectation is sublinear in $t$, for example whenever $t=m$, and $n$ itself grows sublinearly in $t$. But this is probably not very interesting, and you might want to be more specific about what regimes you are actually interested in.

Comment: Thank you James. For the time being let's suppose that we exclude the case where there is no set of bins satisfying both (1) and (2). I am interested in the case where $t\le m/2$. I think the cse where $t=o(m)$ may be easy but the case $t=\Theta(m)$ is more difficult.